# How to calculate growth rate from two different columns to a new column with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know if there is a way to calculate crossed (if i can i name it crossed) from two different columns with that way of calculating growth rate.

**I use this code but the result is in that** :

```r
timeline_Cases_per_city_diff %>%
  group_by(week,county) %>%
  mutate(growth_rate = (metavoli_diff_per_week / metavoli)* 100)
```

Also lag() function doesnt work

[image]

**Desired Result inside the mutate**
(189/308)*100 .....
(64/497)*100 etc..  *which the result is = 12.87726*

With few words i want to calculate the growth rate of the previous week & next weeks (metavoli_diff_per_week) from the next week for all the weeks in a new column

```
structure(list(`Γεωγραφικό Διαμέρισμα` = c("Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", 
"Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", 
"Ελλάδα"), Περιφέρεια = c("Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", 
"Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα", "Ελλάδα"), 
    county_normalized = c("ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", 
    "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ", "ΕΛΛΑΔΑ"
    ), county = c("Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", 
    "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", 
    "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", 
    "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", 
    "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό", "Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό"
    ), pop_11 = c(10816286, 10816286, 10816286, 10816286, 10816286, 
    10816286, 10816286, 10816286, 10816286, 10816286), date = structure(c(18329, 
    18336, 18338, 18350, 18357, 18364, 18370, 18371, 18378, 18384
    ), class = "Date"), cum_cases = c(36, 174, 230, 435, 661, 
    689, 810, 810, 937, 1040), cases = c(8, 103, 35, 95, 60, 
    33, 11, 0, 11, 8), cases_07da = c(6.42857142857143, 20.8571428571429, 
    -0.714285714285714, 20.2857142857143, 17, 40.1428571428571, 
    11.4285714285714, 9.28571428571429, 23.4285714285714, -79
    ), weekday = c("Κυριακή", "Κυριακή", "Τρίτη", "Κυριακή", 
    "Κυριακή", "Κυριακή", "Σάββατο", "Κυριακή", "Κυριακή", "Σάββατο"
    ), week = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18), metavoli = c(36, 
    138, 56, 299, 226, 28, 121, 121, 127, 103), metavoli_diff_per_week = c(NA, 
    102, -82, 243, -73, -198, 93, 0, 6, -24)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show few rows of data and the expected output.  It is difficult to copy from images for testing

Comment: "Also lag() function doesnt work": How did you use it? It seems very appropriate here.

Comment: Because the result is NaN, Na and 0

Comment: @akrun I am new and i dont know how to use dput

Comment: It's simple: type in `dput(head(timeline_Cases_per_city_diff,10))`, copy the output from it (should start with `structure`), then [edit] your question and paste the input into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: `timeline_cases_per_city_diff %>% group_by(week, county) %>% mutate(growth = 100 * metavoli_diff_per_week / lag(metavoli))`. By the definition of lagged calculations, the first result for each group will be `NA` (since there is no preceding data). You can choose to replace this `NA` with another reasonable value by one of several techniques, but they depend on the context of the data. Over to you to determine what is best there.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the quick response about dput. There are more columns with Nan and NA too. Check the full code and help me with an example if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has one row for most weeks (only one has two rows). You can't calculate growth on one row. I think what you *mean* is to group by `county` and *order by* (`arrange(.)`) `week`.

(I'm selecting out the first few columns, since my emacs/ess setup isn't printing the strings. Just a distraction, you should not use my `select`.)

```r
timeline_Cases_per_city_diff %>%
  select(-(1:3)) %>%
  arrange(week) %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  mutate(growth = 100 * metavoli_diff_per_week / lag(metavoli)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 11
#    county                    pop_11 date       cum_cases cases cases_07da weekday   week metavoli metavoli_diff_per_~ growth
#    <chr>                      <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>               <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-03-08        36     8      6.43  "      ~    10       36                  NA  NA   
#  2 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-03-15       174   103     20.9   "      ~    11      138                 102 283.  
#  3 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-03-17       230    35     -0.714 "     "     12       56                 -82 -59.4 
#  4 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-03-29       435    95     20.3   "      ~    13      299                 243 434.  
#  5 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-04-05       661    60     17     "      ~    14      226                 -73 -24.4 
#  6 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-04-12       689    33     40.1   "      ~    15       28                -198 -87.6 
#  7 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-04-18       810    11     11.4   "      ~    16      121                  93 332.  
#  8 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-04-19       810     0      9.29  "      ~    16      121                   0   0   
#  9 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-04-26       937    11     23.4   "      ~    17      127                   6   4.96
# 10 "                     ~ 10816286 2020-05-02      1040     8    -79     "      ~    18      103                 -24 -18.9
```

Warning: this assumes that weeks are contiguous, meaning there are no gaps. If there are gaps expected, then you need some more filtering and/or logic to account for the fact that some growth rates will be (silently) exaggerated (biased high), since they'll be looking at growth over multiple weeks instead of just one.

One technique to account for this would be to incorporate the difference in weeks as well:

```r
timeline_Cases_per_city_diff %>%
  select(-(1:3)) %>%
  arrange(week) %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  mutate(growth = 100 * metavoli_diff_per_week / lag(metavoli) / c(NA,diff(week))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(Though you'll have problems in that output, because of below ...)

Another problem is when you have repeated `week` values per `county`, which you do here. That's a different problem altogether, and its resolution depends heavily on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use lag, the first row can't be calculated, because it doesn't exist a previous value, that why the result is NA may be you need to use lead(), but in that case the NA will appear in the last row, not in the first one.

Also in your code you put `metavoli_diff_per_week / metavoli`, but in your example you put 189/308 or (metavoli / metavoli_diff_per_week)

Finally, you can't group by week, because in that case you have only one observation for every (week, county) and you will obtain only NAs

If I understand well, you need a code like this

```
timeline_Cases_per_city_diff %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  mutate(growth_rate = (metavoli_diff_per_week / lag(metavoli))* 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to calculate the `growth_rate` the using only `metavoli`

```
timeline_Cases_per_city_diff %>% 
  arrange(county, week) %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  mutate(growth_rate = ((metavoli/lag(metavoli))-1)*100) %>%
  select(growth_rate, date)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   county [1]
   county                        growth_rate date      
   <chr>                               <dbl> <date>    
 1 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό       NA    2020-03-08
 2 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      283.   2020-03-15
 3 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      -59.4  2020-03-17
 4 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      434.   2020-03-29
 5 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      -24.4  2020-04-05
 6 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      -87.6  2020-04-12
 7 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      332.   2020-04-18
 8 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό        0    2020-04-19
 9 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό        4.96 2020-04-26
10 Χωρίς Γεωγραφικό Προσδιορισμό      -18.9  2020-05-02
```

Comment: intresting approach. it worked too thank you